# JAVA: is the recursive approache the best way to check if json contains a specific key with a specific data value?

Tags: java, json, recursion, org.json

I am looking to test if my json input contains a specific key with a specific value. I used org.joson lib to parse it and test it. I followed a recursive approach.
Is it the best approach to use? or is there a simpler one?

```
public boolean isJsonContains(String dataKey, String dataValue) {
    logger.systemWriteOutput("is JSON data key "+ dataKey + " contains value: " +dataValue,3);  
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;

    if (jsonInput!=null){
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonInput);
        return isJSONObjectContainsKeyAndValue(dataKey, dataValue,jsonObject );
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }       
}

private boolean isJSONObjectContainsKeyAndValue (String dataKey,  String dataValue, JSONObject object){

    String[] keys = JSONObject.getNames(object);
    logger.systemWriteOutput("JSONObject is: "+object.toString(),3);

    for (String key : keys)
    {                   
        boolean result = isJSONKeyContainsValue(key,  dataValue, object);
        if(result)
            return true;
    }
    logger.systemWriteOutput("no value : "+ dataValue +" has been found for id: " +dataKey,3);
    return false;   
}

private boolean isJSONKeyContainsValue (String dataKey,  String dataValue, JSONObject object){

    Object value = object.get(dataKey);         
    if(dataKey.equals(dataKey) && value.toString().equals(dataValue)){
        logger.systemWriteOutput("value of id: " +dataKey+" is: "+value.toString(),3);
        return true;
    }
    else{
        logger.systemWriteOutput("value of id: " +dataKey+" is: "+value.toString(),3);
        //see if that the nested element contains the id
        if (value instanceof JSONArray){
            logger.systemWriteOutput("key array is: "+dataKey,3);
            JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) object.getJSONArray(dataKey);
            logger.systemWriteOutput("key array lenbgth is: "+jsonArray.length(),3);
            return isJSONArrayContainsKeyAndValue(dataKey,dataValue, jsonArray);
        }
        else  if (value instanceof JSONObject){
            return isJSONObjectContainsKeyAndValue(dataKey, dataValue, object.getJSONObject(dataKey));
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean isJSONArrayContainsKeyAndValue(String dataKey, String dataValue, JSONArray jsonArray) {
    boolean result;

    logger.systemWriteOutput("jsonArray is: "+jsonArray.toString(),3);
    logger.systemWriteOutput("jsonArray length is: "+jsonArray.length(),3);

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject jsonobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        result= isJSONObjectContainsKeyAndValue(dataKey, dataValue ,jsonobject);
        if( result)
            return result;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I don't think you can use "recursive" and "best" in the same sentence.

Comment: @guy can you explain why not?

Comment: It's the only way to do it. If it's deep you need to do the recursion with an explicit stack, but it's still a recursive process.

Comment: You're not parsing JSON in this code - you are searching for a value in a JSONObject which has already been parsed. I'd suggest you reword the title.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to parse JSON is to actually use an existing library, like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) or [JSON](http://www.json.org/java/). For example, you could use the `has` method ([doc](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String))) to find if a given key is present.

If you really want to build your own system, then an iterative approach will allow you to use add parallelism to your system. Other than that, it very usually depends on the problem and the implementation which one is "better". Check this [lecture](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/info/courses/spring-98/cs211/lecturenotes/07-recursion.pdf).

Comment: Why are you recommending the library already being used? "I used org.joson lib to parse it and test it"

Comment: I'm recommending using the library and avoiding creating unnecessary methods that it already contains.